# Python BigQuery Storage. Reading multiple streams in parallel

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have the following toy code:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery_storage_v1beta1
import os
import google.auth

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]='key.json'
credentials, your_project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])
bq_storage_client = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.BigQueryStorageClient(credentials=credentials)

table_ref = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.TableReference()
table_ref.project_id = "bigquery-public-data"
table_ref.dataset_id = "libraries_io"
table_ref.table_id = "versions"

parent = "projects/{}".format(your_project_id)
session = client.create_read_session(
    table_ref,
    parent,
    format_=bigquery_storage_v1beta1.enums.DataFormat.ARROW,
    sharding_strategy=(bigquery_storage_v1beta1.enums.ShardingStrategy.BALANCED),
)

reader1 = bq_storage_client.read_rows(bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.StreamPosition(stream=session.streams[0]), timeout=100000)
reader2 = bq_storage_client.read_rows(bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.StreamPosition(stream=session.streams[1]), timeout=100000)

df = pd.concat([reader1.to_dataframe(session),reader2.to_dataframe(session)])
df
```

I used BALANCED ShardingStrategy to initiate more than 1 stream which can be read independently.

BigqueryStorage documentation says:

> However, if you wanted to fan out multiple readers you could do so by
>   having a reader process each individual stream.

I initiated two readers, one for each of streams in the session. Afterwards, two dataframes (1 created from each reader) are concatenated into single one. However this approach doesn't give any speed up compared to the LIQUID ShardingStrategy.

I am trying to make both readers read rows in parallel. However I failed to find anything about parallel stream reading in library documentation.

The questions are:

1) Does BugQuery Storage provide any native means for reading multiple streams simultaneously if BALANCED ShardingStrategy is chosen?

2) What is best way to read stream in parallel? Do I need to use multiprocessing or asyncio for that?

3) I would appreciate if anyone could provide any basic example on parallel streams reding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `requested_streams` value:

```
n_streams = 2
session = client.create_read_session(
    table_ref,
    parent,
    requested_streams=n_streams,
    format_=bigquery_storage_v1beta1.enums.DataFormat.ARROW,
    sharding_strategy=(bigquery_storage_v1beta1.enums.ShardingStrategy.BALANCED),
)
```

You can concat the dataframes in one line:

```py
readers = []
for i in range(n_streams):
    stream = session.streams[i]
    position = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.types.StreamPosition(stream=stream)
    reader = bqstorageclient.read_rows(position)
    readers.append(reader)
df = pd.concat([reader.to_dataframe(session) for reader in readers])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

[BigQuery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/) does support multiple streams but your execution method does not. You could create multiple instance of readers, then each of them can use individual streams to increase the throughput.

You have many options to do [Parallel processing in python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing). However, the easiest one to use is the [multiprocessing package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Another option is to use [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#storage-api) which supports parallel processing by default but may not be suitable for your use-case. It has a built-in BigQuery IO driver but it's python version doesn't yet support the BigQuery Storage API, so you may have to write your own implementation for the BQ Storage API.

Comment: 'but your execution method does not' could you please elaborate on this? I created two readers and I have two streams, each individual stream is used by 1 reader. What am I doing wrong? What is needed to be changed to use multiple streams?

Comment: You are reading in serial fashion, reader2 will only be processed after reader1 is processed. This is called line by line execution. What you want is to fire individual processes for reader1 and reader2 and let them process in parallel.

Comment: @KunalDeo Can you please provide more info on the beam custom driver? I guess one of the issues of implementing such thing in beam, is that by default and based on beam's parallel execution env, we can't shard one huge read operation into smaller parts (since we don't know how many workers will run in prd). Then the thing becomes beam running a lot of *single stream* read sessions in parallel, each one individually doing the same thing, not actually complementing each other's missing parts. If you have other ideas, links or anything, It's super appreciated if you could share! :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have made some research and I have realized that you used code from BigQuery Storage API, and you are right, the balanced strategy is used if you're consuming , multiple streams, it needs to be mentioned that it is still on beta release.

Some reason of why is this happening is that maybe you are seeing only 1 stream because the data is relatively "small" for the stream allocation algorithm, the number of streams may be lower than the requested number depending on 2 factors: a reasonable parallelism for the table and the service’s limit. Currently, the details of the algorithm to determine what is “reasonable” are not publicly available and are something that may change once the API reaches the general availability phase.

Also you can try the [multiprocessing package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) that has been recommended above.