# BigQuery Storage API run streams in parallel

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to fetch a huge BigQuery table using the BigQuery Storage API. Currently, I'm fetching data sequentially using one stream. The program will run on a server using dozens of virtual CPUs so I want to parallelise the fetching of the table to gain performance.
The version of bq storage I'm using is `google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1`
I saw in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080742/python-bigquery-storage-reading-multiple-streams-in-parallel) that it is possible to specify a sharding strategy to BALANCED in order to compute multiple streams in parallel but it looks like it do not exists in v1.

This option seems to exist in v1_beta but I can't find it in the [code of the repo](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-storage).
Does this option still exist? Or how could I implement parallel sessions otherwise?

```py
from google.cloud.bigquery_storage import types
from google.cloud import bigquery_storage

def get_df_parallel():
    num_cores = 12
    bqclient = BigQueryClient()
    bqstorageclient = bigquery_storage.BigQueryReadClient(credentials=CREDENTIALS)

    stringify_table = f"..."
    parent = "projects/{}".format(VARIABLES['PROJECT_ID'])
    
    requested_session = types.ReadSession(
        table=stringify_table,
        data_format=types.DataFormat.ARROW,
    )
    read_session = bqstorageclient.create_read_session(
        parent=parent, 
        read_session=requested_session, 
        max_stream_count=num_cores,

        # module 'google.cloud.bigquery_storage_v1.gapic_types' has no attribute 'ShardingStrategy'
        sharding_strategy=(types.ShardingStrategy.BALANCED),
    )
    readers = []
    for stream in read_session.streams:
        position = bigquery_storage.types.StreamPosition(stream=stream)
        reader = bqstorageclient.read_rows(position)
        readers.append(reader)
    df = pd.concat([reader.to_dataframe(session) for reader in readers])
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

`bigquery_storage_v1beta1` is already on the process of deprecation and support was removed, thus no python docs exists. Though it is still accessible if you will be following the [v1beta1 RPC reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta1#bigquerystorage) and `ShardingStrategy` still exists in v1beta1 if imported. But still, it is best to avoid using it as the library will be in the near future.

> The v1beta1 API is not yet officially deprecated, and will go through
> a full deprecation cycle
> (https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages) before the
> service is turned down. However, new code should use the v1 API going
> forward.

As per [BigQuery storage v1 python docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquerystorage/latest/index.html#next-steps), you can use [multiprocessing.Process](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) to create parallel processes. You can try implementing this method.

> Because this client uses grpcio library, it is safe to share instances
> across threads. In multiprocessing scenarios, the best practice is to
> create client instances after the invocation of os.fork() by
> multiprocessing.Pool or multiprocessing.Process.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm gonna use v1 with multiprocessing.Process, even if it is complicated to pass complex objects threw processes..